# pandas groupby two data frames without merging

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have two can't mergeable DataFrame. 
In fact, doing some transform can make them mergeable, but would cost much much more memory.

The two dataframe index are DatatimeIndex, but not equal. They both have columns `product_id` and `store_id` . I want to select rows have same `product_id` and `store_id`  in two dataframes and do the process.

My current working code:

```
with tqdm(total=product_ids.shape[0]*store_ids.shape[0]) as t:
    for product_id in product_ids:
        p1 = df1.loc[(df1.product_id==product_id)]
        p2 = df2.loc[(df2.product_id==product_id)]
        for store_id in store_ids:
            df_oi = p1.loc[(p1.store_id==store_id)]

            t.update()

            if df_oi.shape[0] < 14:
                continue

            df_sql = p2.loc[(p2.store_id==store_id)]

            train_predict(df_oi, df_sql)


def train_predict(df_orderitems, df_stockquantitylog):

    store_id = df_orderitems.store_id[0]
    product_id = df_orderitems.product_id[0]

    s = df_stockquantitylog.resample('T').ffill().resample('H').sum()
    daily_stockout_hour = stack_index_to_hour_columns(s, hours=range(7, 21))

    daily_orderitems = resample_orderitems_by_day(df_orderitems)

    if daily_orderitems.shape[0] < 30:
        return

    df_userstat = read_today_userstat(db, store_id, start_date)

    if (daily_orderitems.index[-1] - df_userstat.index[0]).days < 30:
        return

    df = daily_orderitems.join(daily_stockout_hour)  
    ....
    ....
```

As you see, I do transform in `train_predict`, which can reduce much memory usage. But here are too many selections which make my program very slow, groupby is more efficient.

---

Now I write code as

```
g1 = df1.groupby(['product_id', 'store_id'])
g2 = df2.groupby(['product_id', 'store_id'])
g2dict = dict(i for i in g2)

def train_predict_sale_count(df_orderitems):
    store_id = df_orderitems.store_id[0]
    product_id = df_orderitems.product_id[0]
    df_stockquantitylog = g2dict[(product_id, store_id)]
    ...
    ...

tqdm.pandas()
g1.progress_apply(train_predict_sale_count) # progressbar is also efficient write use progress_apply.
```

This is fine, but not my purpose .

Need notice that `zip` not work :

```
for p1, p2 in zip(g1, g2):
    func(p1[1], p2[1])
```

Because here `p1[0] != p2[0]` . `p1[0]` is key [store_id, product_id] , I need `p1[0]` equal to `p2[0]`

So how do I groupby two data frames without merging?

Comment: How about grouping df1 and slicing df2 from keys of df1?

Comment: @Raunaq Jain My method 2 is better than slicing. `g2dict = dict(i for i in g2)` . But if I need use multiprocessing , it has to  produce multiple copys of `g2dict`.

Comment: There's too much code and text here. How about a [mcve]?